# What should the [microsoft] tag be used for?

Tags: discussion, tags

Initially, I assumed [microsoft](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) (132) is about the **company**. But I took a brief look through them and didn't find any about the company.

In fact, all the question seem to be about various Microsoft products. Which means, it's hardly helpful at all.

I guess we could remove the tag from all the questions and reserve the tag for questions about the company. But then again, how could those ever be on-topic?

From another brief look, I guess similar things could be asked about [apple](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apple).

Comment: @DanielBeck: Oh wow :D I guess the problem is bigger than I thought.