# Lotus tag cleanup

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

While looking through some questions on [lotus-notes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lotus-notes), I found that some of them were also tagged with [lotus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lotus), which has 34 questions.  Looking through the [lotus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lotus), many of them are just about Notes, one is about Domino (probably belongs on Server Fault), and there are a few stragglers about Approach, 123, etc.

So my proposal, if no one objects, is to pull [lotus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lotus) from the Notes-related questions, and introduce any new tags as required for the remaining questions.

Incidentally, I noticed that there's a [microsoft](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft), which led me to [this question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5425/what-should-the-microsoft-tag-be-used-for) and a general discussion of company tag cleanups.  So I suspect making [lotus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lotus) disappear will be a good thing.

Comment: that sounds good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done.  The Notes questions were retagged to the existing tag, and two new tags were introduced for Approach and 1-2-3.  The one Domino question was migrated to ServerFault, where I hope it will have a long and productive life.