# Cleaning [gigabyte] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I saw that the [gigabyte](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gigabyte) tag said "Use this tag for questions concerning gigabyte technology, a hardware manufaturer - not filesize." (I also submitted a suggested edit for the typo in the tag wiki - it previously said `manufaturer`.)

In that light, I made the following suggested edits:

https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/296709
https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/296713
https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/296714
https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/296715
https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/296716
https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/296718
https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/296719

I'm not sure what the correct way to batch clean up tags like this is, so I made a meta question. Can we go through [gigabyte](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gigabyte) questions so that the tag is used in a useful manner?

Comment: No need for an extra post, people will get to the review queue sooner or later. The tag is pointless in all regards btw and should be removed on sight.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Even where it's about the hardware manufacturer?

Comment: @Pimgd - yup. See this meta about Manufacturer/Company tags: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again