# Possible Tag Merge: [toshiba-satellite] into [toshiba-laptop]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-cleanup-request

As part of the [Manufacturer & Company tags](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again) cleanup, I'm removing [toshiba](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/toshiba) and replacing it with a more topic/product-centric [toshiba-laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/toshiba-laptop) (for laptop-related questions anyway).

However I've just noticed that we have a [toshiba-satellite](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/toshiba-satellite) tag as well, referring to the particular sub-brand of laptop.

Should we merge (and possibly synonymise) this tag into the [toshiba-laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/toshiba-laptop) tag, or leave it as-is?

Comment: Merge.  Satellite doesn't add value over laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[toshiba-satellite](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/toshiba-satellite) was synonymised with [toshiba-laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/toshiba-laptop)