# Remove [asus-g73jh] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-cleanup-request

[asus-g73jh](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/asus-g73jh) has two questions. It is obviously too specific, I believe in both cases just [asus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/asus) would fit better.

I am new to the whole tag cleanup/merge/remove concept and I am still trying to figure it out. Couldn't find any info/faq on how to handle tag removal. I am not 10k+ user. So do I just delete the tag from all questions or do I post the summary here? Or does it have to be synonymized with [asus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/asus)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete them, and *don't* change them to asus - [we'd prefer not to have company specific tags](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again). I'd do it myself, but meh, why should I have all the fun. Just let us know once this is done so I can swap out the status-planned for status completed.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the explantion.

Comment: For the record, there's probably other asus-laptop questions. Similar to the Toshiba ones, I'll probably create an [asus-laptop] whilst in the process of cleaning out [asus]. These two questions could be a part of that.

Comment: @Robotnik What's special about Asus laptops? Why do they need their own category/tag? In what way are they, as a group, different from other laptops significantly enough to justify that?

Comment: Drivers, support, common issues & bugs specific to asus laptops?

Comment: I do agree with Robotnik. Laptops have their own specifics. Also laptops of one manufacturer often share similar problems.