# Please make [amazon] stop hurting my brain

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

I started to write a tag cleanup request for [amazon](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/amazon), listing the different ways in which the tag is used.  I got writer's cramp.  Basically, if you can create an anagram that spells "amazon" from letters in the question, it gets an [amazon] tag.  The vast majority of these questions either use [amazon] to unnecessarily supplement an amazon-related specific tag, or have no substantive relevance to anything amazon (like how do I perform image manipulation on a picture I originally downloaded from amazon.com).  Please make it go away.

Comment: Can you help me? How do I use my kindle which I bought from Amazon?

Comment: *I bought a book from Amazon and it hasn't arrived help!* `[amazon][windows-7][networking][windows-8][os-x]`.

Comment: In all seriousness though, it's a company tag. I've added it to [the list](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again) :)

Comment: OK, it's on the list.  But please hurry!  This one is really, really bad.

Comment: Many thanks to @kurast for removing the Amazon tag from the question referred to in my example.

Comment: wouldn't amazon-web-services (AWS) actually be the tag you want ?

Comment: @Sirex - for what, specifically?  There are a few questions in that mess for which that would be appropriate.  Only some of the questions relate to that.

Comment: yeah didn't make that clear, sorry - for the ones that have (for some reason) both amazon and amazon web services tags.

Comment: You're right.  Hopefully, [amazon] will disappear, but as a general rule, there shouldn't be both a specific tag and a generic one for the same thing.

Comment: Why? No Maza (person meant no mazda) would get an amazon tag @fixer1234