# Let's dellete [dell]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

There are currently 1002 questions tagged [dell](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dell).

According to [Manufacturer & Company tags are back. Again](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again):

> We don't like company-only tags, and there's been various crusades in the past to purge them

Should we cleanup [dell](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dell)?

There is also [dell-inspiron](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dell-inspiron) (282 questions) and [dell-latitude](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dell-latitude) (122 questions). Should they go as well?

Please discuss.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking.  Dell is already in the list of manufacturer meta tags, with status planned.  Anybody can clean up those tags at will.  The ones that are left tend to have huge numbers of questions, which is why they're still there (not low-hanging fruit).  [dell-inspiron] and [dell-latitude] are product-specific tags.  One could argue the need (are there problems specific to these product lines, and experts whose knowledge is limited to those product lines?).  They actually have 5 and 7 followers, respectively, which would suggest the tags are serving a purpose.

Comment: @fixer1234 Ah. Ok. I will clean [dell] up as I see it ;)

Comment: And [dell-optiplex] and [optiplex].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see much of a point in [dell](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dell) - it seems to be used for all manner of things that really aren't Dell-specific, from [networking issues](https://superuser.com/questions/986210/windows-7-laptop-showing-network-as-unidentified) to [power problems](https://superuser.com/questions/576190/dell-inspirion-545-desktop-will-not-power-on-possible-solutions) to [OS-specific questions](https://superuser.com/questions/687413/cant-find-windows-8-1-in-store-after-kb-2871389-install-and-wsreset-exe) to [power management surprises](https://superuser.com/questions/1003673/windows-10-changes-power-management-settings). There might be Dell support people on the site, but in the current way [dell](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dell) is used, nobody can be an expert in it. It would be nice if we could get [dell](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dell) to be used only for things that are actually directly caused by or related to Dell hardware, but at the moment, people are just slathering it on anything incidental to Dell.

I think the Dell model tags, however, actually have some usefulness. Model tags should (in my opinion) be used for hardware servicing questions on those models. Machine models can have certain idiosyncrasies, properties, and problems. It is entirely conceivable that somebody could be an expert on the [dell-inspiron](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dell-inspiron)'s hardware, and I would be open to retagging such [dell](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dell) questions to carry the model tag.