# Pew Pew the Laser Tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

While working my way through the [manufacturer tag clean up list](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8402/393570) I came across the tag [laser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/laser).

It has no description and the questions listed all appear to refer to [laser-printer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/laser-printer). Am I ok to remove this tag or would a tag synonym be more appropriate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have removed all of these now. The majority required the [laser-printer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/laser-printer) tag adding. There were a few talking about optical mice but not enough for a new tag of [optical-mouse](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/optical-mouse) so I left these as [mouse](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mouse).

Answer (score 10):

Set Lasers to Kill. Leave none standing. Feels like the classic MetaTag. I'm doubtful the average end user will be working directly on a laser sans other context.

Comment: And those who are wokin gon it might be better of on Physics or another website. :)