# Is there a method to rename a tag without editing the questions?

Tags: discussion, retagging

I just added [apache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apache) to the manufacturer meta tag list because Apache is a software foundation with an extensive list of projects, not just the web server software.  The [apache] tag has been used for other products, and these can be cleaned up.  Many are cases of redundant tagging where [apache] is just decoration.

After cleanup, however, there will be close to 2,200 questions where [apache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apache) refers to the web server software.  Manually retagging would be a massive job, and will flood the main page.  Is there a mechanism to directly revise the tag name (to something like [apache-http-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apache-http-server)), that can be used after the other usage is cleaned out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can't edit a tag directly, what we can do is created a synonym for [apache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apache) as [apache-http-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apache-http-server), swap it as the main tag and do a merge.

--

Actually just did this:

```
Updating post history, 2563 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 2241 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [apache-http-server] and [apache] complete!
remapping 1 synonyms
235 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
1695 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Comment: Neat!  I should probably clean up the manufacturer meta tag thread, and I guess we can clean up the questions with the [apache] tag changed.  Is there a way to prevent [apache] from being reused incorrectly, or we just rely on the user catching that [apache-http-server] is what shows up on the question?

Comment: we can remove the synonym now, since the tag [tag:apache] has been deleted and will require rep to create, but tbh I'd prefer to let it be as is for now