# Synonomize Red Hat tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

[redhat](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/redhat) is among the remaining manufacturer meta tags.  Roughly 500 of the questions have been cleaned up; the ones needing general tag remediation.  About 136 questions remain.  All of these refer to RHEL.

[rhel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rhel) (482 questions), is not an ideal tag name because many people think in terms of "Red Hat" rather than the "RHEL" acronym.  I created [redhat-enterprise-linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/redhat-enterprise-linux) as a more intuitive tag, and beefed up the wiki and excerpt.

Rather than manually retag the remaining [redhat] questions and flood the main page, we can kill two birds with one stone by synonomizing tags:

- Make [redhat](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/redhat) a synonym of [redhat-enterprise-linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/redhat-enterprise-linux), with the latter as the primary tag.  That will complete [redhat] cleanup and link it for future users who try to use it.
- Make [rhel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rhel) a synonym of [redhat-enterprise-linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/redhat-enterprise-linux), with the latter as the primary tag.  That will link [rhel] for people who think in terms of the acronym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done

```
updating post history, 537 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 482 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 482 rows affected
updating Documentation tag proposal commitments, 0 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [redhat-enterprise-linux] and [rhel] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
32 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
29 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym rhel -> redhat-enterprise-linux was approved!
```

---

```
updating post history, 162 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 134 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 134 rows affected
updating Documentation tag proposal commitments, 0 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [redhat-enterprise-linux] and [redhat] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
89 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
24 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym redhat -> redhat-enterprise-linux was approved!
```