# Should we pair [unifying-receiver] with other [logitech-*] tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Logitech product tags exist in the form of `[logitech-*]` as outlined by yours truly on the [Manufacturer & Company tag meta](https://meta.superuser.com/a/8652/107240).

However there's currently an outlier, which is the *Logitech Unifying Receiver*, a nifty device that can sync with multiple Logitech devices. This is currently tagged [unifying-receiver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unifying-receiver), because [logitech-unifying-receiver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/logitech-unifying-receiver) was too long at 27 characters.

**However**, given the recent SE-wide [tag length increase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/179041) to 35 characters, we could rename [unifying-receiver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unifying-receiver) to [logitech-unifying-receiver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/logitech-unifying-receiver) and bring it in line with the other tags.

Thoughts?

Comment: Seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: @Mokubai - It's been almost two years, would you have a moment to action this tag rename? It's something I could do in 19 edits, but I'd rather not spam the front page with tiny edits :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done.

```
updating post history, 26 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 19 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'logitech-unifying-receiver' doesn't exist, renaming to 'unifying-receiver'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [logitech-unifying-receiver] and [unifying-receiver] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym unifying-receiver -> logitech-unifying-receiver was approved!
```

I also created a synonym as I'm not sure anyone else does a "unifying receiver". If someone tells me otherwise then I'll break the link.