# Retag [mikrotik] to [mikrotik-routeros] or [mikrotik-swos]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[mikrotik](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mikrotik) is a manufacturer meta-tag. Mikrotik makes a variety of routers, but for all intents and purposes they have two main products: RouterOS and SwOS (their operating system for switches). I suggest we retag [mikrotik](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mikrotik) to [mikrotik-routeros](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mikrotik-routeros) or [mikrotik-swos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mikrotik-swos), depending on the topic.

Note: [mikrotik](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mikrotik) is slated for deletion and listed [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again).

Comment: Might [mikrotik-router] and [mikrotik-switch] be more intuitive and generic?  I take it RouterOS and SwOS are product lines?  I'm just wondering whether any posters not familiar with the product line names might find the tags confusing (and OS is typically used for Operating System).  Also, if Mikrotik introduces new product lines of similar products, the product-specific tag might not seem to fit.

Comment: @fixer1234 RouterOS is Mikrotik's operating system for routers. They sell hardware built for it, but the main product is the software (you can just buy an OS license without buying one of their routers). Similar situation for SwitchOS.

Comment: That makes sense.  This is out of my area.  I was just aware that they made hardware.  Are the questions here mostly about the OS rather than the hardware?  Is it common for people to just buy the OS license and run it on their own hardware?  Also, if some of the questions are about the hardware, might [mikrotik-router] and [mikrotik-switch] apply to either hardware, OS, or both (I'm thinking about the most generic way to do it)?

Comment: @fixer1234 I can't think of any hardware questions that would be valid here, as the information would be easily available on Google.

Comment: And, of course, posters here always research on Google before posting.  ROTFL.  OK, you're the one with some expertise.  I'll trust your judgment.