# Alias nvidia to nvidia-graphics-card

Tags: discussion, tags

There is no Nvidia tag. Confer, https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nvidia.

It may be a good idea to make [nvidia](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nvidia) an alias for [nvidia-graphics-card](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nvidia-graphics-card).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190914/are-company-name-tags-like-microsoft-and-apple-useful

Comment: I'm onboard for this. We have a post somewhere about removing manufacturer tags...

Comment: Anyone with 2500 rep and a handful of upvotes on questions in a tag can suggest a synonym: https://superuser.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms. If you want to see whether you are eligible then you can go to your (main site) profile page and in the search box (which should now have your user number filled in) type `[nvidia-graphics-card]`.

Answer (score 4):

[nvidia](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nvidia) is a manufacturer meta tag that has already been deprecated.  See [Manufacturer & Company tags are back. Again](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again).

A separate, synonomized [nvidia](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nvidia) tag isn't really needed because as soon as the user starts typing nvidia in the tag area, [nvidia-graphics-card] automatically pops up (along with other nvidia options).

In the comments, you mentioned that the actual issue is trying to search on [nvidia](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nvidia), which returns no matches.  If we recreate the [nvidia](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nvidia) tag and synonomize it with [nvidia-graphics-card](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nvidia-graphics-card), that creates a different problem.  There are seven nvidia-related tags, and the resulting search on [nvidia](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nvidia) would exclude roughly a third of the nvidia questions.  So the results would be misleading.

You can search on the word "nvidia" rather than the tag, but that isn't perfect, either.  In the question, posters may refer to the "model name" of the card without mentioning "nvidia", so the search wouldn't capture everything.

There's actually a solution that isn't advertised, so people might not think to try it.  You can use wildcards in tag name search terms.  Searching on [nvidia*] returns everything with a tag name starting with "nvidia".  It might be helpful for SE to include that information in the search help.  I posted a [suggestion to do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340650/269940) on Meta SE.

Comment: In the vocabulary of techies, Nvidia is a video card. It is also a company, but the primary use refers to their video cards. Stack Overflow and Super User of full of the video card use. Does anyone use the term Nvidia to mean the company and not the video card?

Comment: @jww, Nvidia is commonly known for their graphics-related hardware, but they're also into other stuff, like parallel processing and AI.  In any event, a separate, synonomized tag isn't really needed because as soon as the user starts typing nvidia in the tag area, [nvidia-graphics-card] automatically pops up.

Comment: *synonomized tag isn't really* - Not true. I wasted about 5 minutes trying to figure why searching for `[nvidia]` was producing 0 results. It broke usability on the site. I also could not find anything related to SoCs or AI. This is what happens when engineers make usability decisions. They argue for cases that don't exist in practice, and other engineers with no common sense agree with them.

Comment: @jww, LOL.  Yeah, if you specifically search using [nvidia], there aren't any matching results.  But it took you 5 minutes to figure it out?  More coffee might have shortened that time.  :-)  The thing is, there are a bunch of nvidia tags, so synonomizing nvidia with [nvidia-graphics-card] would return misleading results, excluding the other tags.  Entering nvidia in the search box on the tag page returns everything.  If we synonomize it, someone else will complain that their search returned only partial results.  Search with the word "nvidia" instead of the tag.