# Why no tag for AnyDesk, and can it be created?

Tags: support, tags

There are currently [35 questions that contain the word AnyDesk](https://superuser.com/search?q=%22AnyDesk%22+is%3Aq), however there's no tag to it.

I thought maybe it's a global "no commercial tags" policy, but there is a [teamviewer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/teamviewer) tag.

So this leads me to ask: why there's no tag for AnyDesk? Can it please be added?

Answer (score 6):

The main reason is probably that the users creating questions lack the reputation to create a new tag. Creation of a new tag requires [300 reputation](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/create-tags). Apart from yourself at a quick glance it appears most people posting from your search have less than 300.

As long as it refers to the program [rather than the company](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again) I do not see a reason for you not to simply add the new tag to [your own question](https://superuser.com/questions/1574772/mouse-not-working-properly-after-using-anydesk-for-long-time) and go from there.

The tag is specific, the only thing would be in creating a useful [tag excerpt](https://superuser.com/help/tag-excerpts) and description page.

Answer (score -5):

> why there's no tag for AnyDesk?

Currently, there are 446,979 questions asked on super user. At 35 questions (0.007%), AnyDesk is not important enough (yet?). There are several alternatives already in use ((VPN +) RDP, team viewer, etc.).

> Can it please be added?

Given the aforementioned, most certainly not.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a valid reason for not having a tag, in my opinion.

Comment: Shouldn't tag creation be dicated by demand? 300 rep is too low of a low threshold. Why spam countless tags that no one watches/knows about? There isn't even a user base capable of answering questions as such throughly (AnyDesk is proprietary/does not seem to offer free support).

Comment: Isn't the whole point of this community to get questions answered? I don't really care about formatting, feelings, being nice as long as I get/am able to write helpful answers.

Comment: @Kev - You are expected to be polite towards all users even those users who you disagree with.

Comment: "I don't really care about ... feelings, being nice" Then you are breaking our [code of conduct](https://superuser.com/conduct) - and not for the first time.

Comment: @Kev you can start a new feature request, since what you ask is related to the whole network of sites, it should be posted on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), with title like "Make tag creation be only on demand" and explain why such a change will be better than what we have today.