# Is the "microsoft" tag of any use?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have found a tag named [microsoft](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) which was created August 26 with 10 questions. Does the tag have any use, or should it be removed?

Comment: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again Simply remove the tags from those questions as far as I'm concerned. It is a meta tag (requires other tags to be even vaguely useful) and as such is a waste of effort to be applied in the first place.

Comment: @Mokubai I have edited the 10 questions and removed the [tag:microsoft] tag, now should I delete this question?

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps close it as a duplicate so we have a little history? The question is valid, so outright deletion seems slightly wrong...

Comment: Yes @Mokubai the post has been closed by now.